# How to send a string on Python Flask route to a JS function?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

This is the route on `app.py`

```
app.route('/analyze', methods=['POST'])
async def analyze(requestArg):
    img_data = await requestArg.form()
    img_bytes = await (img_data['file'].read())
    img = open_image(BytesIO(img_bytes))
    prediction = learn.predict(img)[0]
    result(str(prediction))
```

I'm trying to send the `str(prediction)` to the `result()` function on `static/js/script.js` here

```
function result(str) {
    $(".pd-result").show();

    var resultText = $(".text")
    switch (str) {
        case "emotion":
            text.html("angry");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
};
```

I've tried to just directly call `result(str(prediction))` but it doesn't work.

Comment: a) you can't just mix JavaScript and Python randomly (or non-randomly) b) the Python code runs on the server, and that JS code is client-side code and therefore runs in the user's browser. You need to use [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to make a request to the server's `/analyze` route, then process the result in the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.py` return `prediction`:

```
app.route('/analyze', methods=['POST'])
async def analyze(requestArg):
    img_data = await requestArg.form()
    img_bytes = await (img_data['file'].read())
    img = open_image(BytesIO(img_bytes))
    prediction = learn.predict(img)[0]
    return prediction
```

Within your js file call you function on a successfull post request:

```
$(() => {
    Var data = {...};
    $.post("/analyze", data)
        .done((prediction)=>{
            result(prediction)
        }))
})
```

See here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: You are right - you have to use ` $.post() `. This should work since you are already using jQuery. I fixed my code.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really familiar with Ajax so I wasn't sure what went wrong.